# Trying to send a variable to a route from a button

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to turn the tag with a user's name into a button and send it's id to an edit file.

```
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-center text-secondary align-center">
        <button class="rounded-circle" href="{{  route('users.edit', ['id'=>Auth::User()->id])}}">
            <span class="no-underline hover:underline text-center text-secondary align-bottom">
                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

I tried to do it with Auth::User()->id, but the button doesn't do anything and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: This is simple, change `<button>` to `<a>`, <a> will will redirect you to a page, `<button>` doesn't. I suggest you learn the basics of frontend first like HTML, CSS and JS. Then learn backend PHP basics. Then finally PHP framework Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

use `<a></a>` instead of `<button></button>`  example :

```
<div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-center text-secondary align-center">
        <a class="rounded-circle" href="{{  route('users.edit', ['id'=>Auth::User()->id])}}">
            <span class="no-underline hover:underline text-center text-secondary align-bottom">
                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
            </span>
        </a>
 </div>
```

if you want it to look like a button add `btn` class .

i hope it was useful !

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use button on there use;

```
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-center text-secondary align-center">
        <form id="YOUR_FORM_ID" action="{{  route('users.edit', ['id'=>Auth::User()->id])}}" method="YOUR_METHOD">
            @csrf
        </form>
        <button class="rounded-circle" type="submit" form="YOUR_FORM_ID">
        <span class="no-underline hover:underline text-center text-secondary align-bottom">
            {{ Auth::user()->name }}
        </span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Don't forget to change YOUR_FORM_ID and YOUR_METHOD.
Or else @Joukhar's formula will work.